# What is a good script or free/trial tool to inventory/replicate all settings in master db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Context: CU10 failed, reporting a corrupt master db when applied to SQL Server 2012 SP3 CU5.  We built an empty new master on that server and will restore the backup of the CU5 master into a new CU5 instance on a different server. Now we need to replicate all settings from the restored CU5 master into the newly built CU10 master.

We cannot restore the backup of the CU5 master onto the CU10 instance of course, because the backup is from an older version.  We are not concerned about master encryption key as we have not used SSRS, SSL or encryption on this server.

Comment: Have you checked out https://DBATools.io ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am taking a look at them. I was hoping for a trial commercial tool to ensure completeness, but the community behind dba-tools is fairly impressive, so I am hopeful. It turns out that there does not seem to be much in that instance's configuration that is custom.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way...
1. Connect to instance with CU5 master
2. Right-click master database> tasks> Generate Scripts
3. Wizard is launched for scripting database objects.
To get server principals:
[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)

Or, Powershell!
[Automated Script-generation with Powershell and SMO](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That approach would generate DDL commands, which would not be of much use.  What I need to do is ensure any customized settings and definitions are replicated.  Even if it generated insert statements, that would be risky due to CU level differences and because directly inserting into system tables is strongly discouraged.

Comment: So, what do you actually need? sp_configure settings?